# How to Plot lines on image by 45 degrees from centroid. I have fitted a bounding box on image and found centroid

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have fitted a bounding box on image which have concerned area is human silhouette in BW, and found centroid according to concerned human silhouette?
now i have to plot red line by 45 degree angle from centroid.
from centroid to vertical, horizental and diagonal logic? Need code in MATLAB?

I have fitted a bounding box on image and found centroid according to concerned human silhouette?

```
% bounding box
labeledImage = bwlabel(Ibw);
blobMeasurements = regionprops(labeledImage, 'BoundingBox');
thisBlobsBoundingBox = blobMeasurements.BoundingBox;  
subImage = imcrop(Ibw, thisBlobsBoundingBox);
figure, imshow(subImage);
imwrite(subImage,fullfile(cd, strcat('Croped By BoundingBox','.png')));
%centroid
Ibw = imread('Croped By BoundingBox.png');
Ibw = imfill(Ibw,'holes');
Ilabel = bwlabel(Ibw);
stat = regionprops(Ilabel,'centroid');
imshow(Ibw),hold on;
for x = 1: numel(stat)
    plot(stat(x).Centroid(1),stat(x).Centroid(2),'ro');
     [rows, cols] =ndgrid(1:size(Ibw, 1), 1:size(Ibw, 2));
    centroidrowcol = mean([rows(:) .* Ibw(:), cols(:) .* Ibw(:)]);
    hold on
end
figure, imshow(Ibw);
imwrite(Ibw,fullfile(cd, strcat('Centroid','.png')));
```

plot lines from centroid to vercally horizentally and diagonally by 45 degree from centroid.

i have to obtaon these results
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMBmU.png)

Comment: You've found your centroids and just need lines right? Isn't it just simple `line()`?

Comment: yes, lines at 45 degree from centroid to boundary of image

Comment: What do you mean by 45 degrees? The lines y=x and y=-x shifted to intercept the centroid?

Comment: yes somehow , I have added an image to desired results

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `line()` then? In this case, it's not beyond what the documentation shows.

Comment: And as always, be sure to read the [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and incorporate them in your future questions. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with assuming `centroid`, a length-2 vector, is the coordinates of a centroid -- since you already have them.

As a reminder, 45 degree lines centered at (0,0) are the images of the functions f(x)=x and f(x)=-x. In order to shift the lines to intercept points of your choice, say (x0, y0), you need f(x-x0)+y0. In other words, f(x)=x-x0+y0 and f(x)=-x+x0+y0 respectively.

Knowing the functions (whose images are) the lines of your desire, there are a number of things you can do in order to complete the task. You can define Matlab functions as such and plot the usual way with `plot`, or for a quick display, with `ezplot`:

```
ezplot(@(x)x-centroid(1)+centroid(2));
```

[`line()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) in Matlab allows you to draw a line segment between two points in 2D, among other things. With `line()`, you actually don't have to know the equations explicitly. You just need two points. So, one possibility is that you use `[centroid(1)+1, centroid(2)+1]` as your first point and `[centroid(1)-1, centroid(2)-1]` as your second point for the shifted f(x)=x line.

Just read the documentation for the correct syntax. In the above example, you would put in

```
line([centroid(1)+1;centroid(1)-1], [centroid(2)+1;centroid(2)-1]);
```

This draws a 45 degree line segment alright. You also want the length of the line segment to be visually sensible. You can either autoscale the length, ie. change the `1` into a formula, based on the size of your image. OR, you can make sure your segment is longer than the extent of the image but confine your plot to a certain size by changing `xlim` and `ylim`.